# What's the point of this left join?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, teradata

When I use BigQuery to query these two tables it seems like this left join is pointless. It left joins PD into PI on `PD.STR_NBR = PI.STR_NBR` but then filters by `PD.STR_NBR IS NULL`.

```
SELECT
      PI.CUST_ORD_NBR AS CUST_ORD_NBR,
      PI.STR_NBR AS STR_NBR,
      PI.SKU_NBR AS SKU_NBR
FROM
      PURCH_ITEM_ID PI
LEFT JOIN
      PROF_BID_DTL_W7 PD
   ON PD.CUST_ORD_NBR = PI.CUST_ORD_NBR
  AND PD.STR_NBR = PI.STR_NBR -- checks equality
  AND CAST(PD.SKU_NBR AS STRING) = PI.SKU_NBR
WHERE PD.STR_NBR IS NULL -- filters by null
;
```

I don't know if it's relevant but I'll mention this BQ code has been transitioned from Teradata sql.

Comment: it seems like your query wont produce any results. as NULL = NULL doesn't produces results.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This gives you all the records with a combination of str_nbr,CUST_ORD_NBR, and skus's that are present in PURCH_ITEM_ID but not PROF_BID_DTL_W7

Edit: RToyo posted a good explanation in the comments.

Just for completeness. Take this example

```
TableA

Key      Value
1        A
2        B
3        C

TableB
Key      Value
1        A
2        B
```

The WHERE clause applies to the intermediate result set.

So if I join

```
SELECT *
  FROM TableA A
  LEFT
  JOIN TableB B
    ON A.Key = B.Key
   AND A.Value = B.Value
```

Result set is going to be

```
Key Value Key   Value 
1   A     1     A
2   B     2     B
3   C     NULL  NULL
```

Because no match was found on {3,C}.

So when I add in that where condition

```
SELECT TableA.*
  FROM TableA A
  LEFT
  JOIN TableB B
    ON A.Key = B.Key
   AND A.Value = B.Value
 WHERE B.Key IS NULL
```

I just get the last record

```
Key Value 
3   C
```

This is logically (and most often implemented the same way by the optimizer) equivalent to

```
SELECT TA.*
  FROM TableA TA
 WHERE NOT EXISTS
         ( SELECT 1
             FROM TableB TB
            WHERE TA.key = TB.key
              AND TA.value = TB.value
         );
```

Comment: To expand on this a little bit: The left (outer) join will attempt to join `PROF_BID_DTL_W7` to your base table, `PURCH_ITEM_I`. But if there are no matching results in your PROF table, then it will still return a row with populated data from the PURCH, and `null` values from the columns coming from the PROF table. So the where clause at the end checks of a column from PROF is null (which, again, happens when there is no match in PROF). In other words, the purpose of this left join is to filter out any rows that already exist in the PROF table.

Comment: I now realize this is equivalent to an excluding left join (middle left): https://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/Visual_SQL_Joins/Visual_SQL_JOINS_orig.jpg

Comment: @Eric Yup, that's the exact thing. You might see people doing IN/NOT IN to achieve this. Do not do IN/NOT IN to achieve this. It's often much less efficient and can have very counter-intuitive results with NULL values.

Comment: Nice explanation which helps me understand the issue and apply the resolution.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have two tables, farmers and bank_savings, each table having details of all such living persons in the USA.
You (an official in the US Dept of Rural Economy) may be *primarily* interested in older farmers with lowish (> $10,000 &  < $20,000) savings accounts. But you may also be interested in other things like (A) farmers over 65 with large acreages or maybe (B) any kind of people with lowish savings accounts.

Using a simple inner JOIN (perhaps on SS No.) gets you the primary information but not all the secondary data (e.g. A and B datasets) of interest.
For additional dataset A only, we can use LEFT JOIN.
For additional dataset B only, we can use RIGHT JOIN.
For both A and B datasets we use FULL JOIN.

Of course we could also set up separate queries for datasets A and B, using simple JOIN for each. But this would be less efficient, especially we are linking to remotely held databases - which is often the case with government data.