# LEFT JOIN … WHERE returning less rows than LEFT JOIN ON + AND

Tags: sql, postgresql, where-clause, left-join

It seems that I totally fail to understand these query results (a PostgreSQL DB):

a) Rows filtered only after joining them:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM apidata.info x
LEFT JOIN compdata.info a
    ON x.info = a.identifier
WHERE
    a.permit_id IS NULL
    AND a.identifier IS NULL;
```

```
count
--------
109242
(1 row)
```

b) Rows filtered only before joining them:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM apidata.info x
LEFT JOIN compdata.info a
    ON x.info = a.identifier
    AND a.permit_id IS NULL
WHERE a.identifier IS NULL;
```

```
count
--------
111981
(1 row)
```

c) Rows filtered both before and after joining them:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM apidata.info x
LEFT JOIN compdata.info a
    ON x.info = a.identifier
    AND a.permit_id IS NULL
WHERE
    a.permit_id IS NULL
    AND a.identifier IS NULL;
```

```
count
--------
111981
(1 row)
```

I don't understand how the queries *b* and *c* can possibly return a **higher** count than query *a*. Especially I would expect the query *c* to return no higher count than the query *a*, yet it returns exactly the same count as the query *b*.

This is with some real data with millions of rows in the source tables (I've generalised the table and field names), but it seems that I cannot imagine any simpler sets that would yield similar results.

What am I missing here? Is anyone able to provide a simpler example?

Comment: Your intention is not clear. Is `permit_id` supposed to be null or are you just looking for rows where the left-join did not match? If the latter you should use `NOT EXISTS`, if the former it's still not clear if you actaully wanted an `INNER JOIN` instead, because `COUNT(*)` will count all rows including the ones which don't get a match. The difference between the queries is because `WHERE` and `ON` do not do the same thing in left-joins.

Comment: I didn't mean to be rude by reopening the question after you closed it, but I felt the combination of factors in this case was so weird that even someone with reasonable knowledge on left joins could get stuck here and the normal answers about left joins wouldn't cover this. Although I might have left it closed if I wasn't about to post my answer in the second you closed it. ;)

Comment: This is a relevant question for the difference between conditions in the join predicate (ON ...) and the where predicate (where ... ) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51197340/whats-the-point-of-this-left-join/51197354#51197354

Comment: It maybe helps that I was trying to simplify a bunch of queries that had been written by others in CTE format, in this case as follows: `WITH my_compdata AS (SELECT info FROM compdata WHERE permit_id IS NULL) SELECT COUNT(*) FROM apidata LEFT JOIN my_compdata ON apidata.info = my_compdata.info WHERE my_compdata.info IS NULL;` That query returns 111981. And yeah, usually I consider myself to be a person with ‘reasonable knowledge on left joins’, but stuck I got. Thank you for your answer @GolezTrol, I'll look into it more closely.

Comment: If you stop and think about it B and C are the same query. You require the inner side to be null for a match otherwise a null will be filled in anyway. So `permit_id` was already guaranteed to be null.

Comment: Consider this: When you move that logic into the left join you are restricting the number of rows that could match which thereby *increases* the potential for outer rows to remain unmatched. Those are the rows that you're counting.

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/J1MVmQEE

Comment: You need to tell us what you expected & why or you are just asking for the manual to be rewritten with no details on what you do or don't understand or misunderstand. Ask about 1 problem query per post. Debug questions require a [mre]. Clearly when you pin down your point of misconception it will be a faq. [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097) PS LEFT JOIN returns INNER JOIN rows UNION ALL unmatched left table rows extended by NULLs. Always know what INNER JOIN you want as part of an OUTER JOIN.

Comment: A [mre] includes: cut & paste & runnable code including initialization; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For SQL include DDL & tabular initialization code. For debug that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. [ask] [Help] When you get a result you don't expect, pause your overall goal, chop to the 1st subexpression with unexpected result & say what you expected & why, justified by documentation. (Debugging fundamental.)

Comment: You have a  slight misconception on how SQL statements are executed. They are not executed in the sequence that they are written.  In the case of JOIN and WHERE, all join conditions are executed before any predicated in the where. So there is actually no such thing as filtered (where) before  join - at least without a subquery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a weird condition:
`x.info = a.identifier` and then `a.identifier IS NULL`.

The `=` operator won't work on nulls. So every row of a where identifier is null will NOT be joined. The where condition, where `a.identifier IS NULL` is therefore useless, since it will always be null. Having only data for the leading table, x.

And there lies the problem.

Query a is filtered more agressively, because

- First you join all compdata rows where identifier is not null (actually matching something in apidata)
- Then remove all rows from the result that had such a match, by checking `a.identifier IS NULL`.

For b and c, you filter less agressively:

- First you join only the rows that have a matching identifier *and* a matching permit_id, so this actually matches fewer rows than the join of query a. For the other rows (so more than in the first query), the columns of compdata will be null, and those are the rows you get back from this query.
- Then you filter out all rows that had a matching join.

Comment: This is likely correct; thank you. I still need to use a bit more time to chew it through though, before I am ready to accept your answer (it doesn't help that this all happens in a rather restricted environment were executing queries is more difficult than it usually is). But yes, likely the nulls are my pitfall here.